# check https status code ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, https

Is there a way to check for an HTTPS status code in ruby? I know that there are ways to do this in HTTP using `require 'net/http'`, but I'm looking for HTTPS. Maybe there is a different library that I need to use?

Comment: You can do this in net/http: http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-cure-nethttps-risky-default-https-behavior-4010.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this in net/http:

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("https://www.secure.com/")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
res = http.request(request)

res.code #=> "200"
```

Refs:

- [Net::HTTP cheat sheet](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html)
- [How to Cure Net::HTTP’s Risky Default HTTPS Behavior](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-cure-nethttps-risky-default-https-behavior-4010.html)

Answer (score 8):

You can use any wrapper around Net::HTTP(S) to get much easier behavior.
I use Faraday here ( https://github.com/lostisland/faraday ) but HTTParty has almost the same functionality ( https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty )

```
 require 'faraday'

 res = Faraday.get("https://www.example.com/")
 res.status # => 200

 res = Faraday.get("http://www.example.com/")
 res.status # => 200
```

(as a bonus you get options for parsing responses, raising state exceptions, logging requests....

```
 connection = Faraday.new("https://www.example.com/") do |conn|
   # url-encode the body if given as a hash
   conn.request :url_encoded
   # add an authorization header
   conn.request :oauth2, 'TOKEN'
   # use JSON to convert the response into a hash
   conn.response :json, :content_type => /\bjson$/
   # ...
   conn.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
 end

 connection.get("/")

  # GET https://www.example.com/some/path?query=string
 connection.get("/some/path", :query => "string")

 # POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH....
 connection.post("/some/other/path", :these => "fields", :will => "be converted to a request string in the body"}

 # add any number of headers. in this example "Accept-Language: en-US"
 connection.get("/some/path", nil, :accept_language => "en-US")
```

Answer (score 5):

```
require 'uri'  
require 'net/http'  

res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI('http://www.example.com/index.html'))  
puts res.code # -> '200'
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more readable way:

`response.kind_of?(Net::HTTPOK)`