# How to test a url which doesn't exist in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I want to validate that **my url in my web application** returns 404 Not found. I know it doesn't exist, but I need to confirm that via tests by Rspec. How? This doesn't work:

```
it "404" do
  get "/some_url_404"
  expect(response.status).to eq 404
end
```

The test itself fails with:

ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/some_url_404"

**update**

the answer hasn't been given yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check https status code ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685599/check-https-status-code-ruby)

Comment: Ruby! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908017/check-if-url-exists-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate place for it is [request spec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) (`spec/requests` subfolder). There the above snippet should work as expected.

Comment: Making the test a request spec doesn't change the underlying default behavior, it will still throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can create a route to match all paths not defined using this:

```
get '*path', to: "controller#action"
```

The `controller` and `action` above denote the controller and action you want all requests for routes not listed should go. Here is how the controller action could be

```
#controller/action

def action
  render(:file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", status: 404)
end
```

#### Note

Make sure the route is placed at the bottom of your route. If not, all requests will end there.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer was covered in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14141836/2687094).

You need to change the following settings in test.rb:

```
consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
```